# How to map child .chm topic to Context Sensitive Help in Robohelp?

Tags: merge, chm, html-help, robohelp, html-help-workshop

Using Robohelp 10 html help. how can i map a topic from a merged (child) .chm to the master?  User needs to press F1 and get the topic from the child .chm.  I tried editing the Master's .ali file and changing the Alias entry, like this:

```
<Alias name="Test" link="child.chm::/test.htm">
```

Can't figure out the format to refer to the child.chm correctly.  In the child or Master itself, if i use

```
<Alias name="Test" link="test.htm">
```

(assuming i put the actual .htm file inside that respective project and i'm not merging them, just testing with that single .chm), it works fine.  I know the name parameter is correct, i just can't get the master to understand to look into the child to get the test.htm file.  The old examples mention a redirect file, but how do i do that with this xml format? **JUST LOOK AT THE EXAMPLES ROBOHELP MAKES WHEN YOU DEFINE A WORKING ONE,  THEY ARE IN THE .ali file**. Is that what i'm missing? **YES** Do i put the mapping into the child at all? **NO**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining context mappings [Creating Context-Sensitive Help for Applications](http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_context-id.htm) works fine in a standalone CHM, but in a merged help system one can run into problems when trying to open a Slave topic though the master CHM.

The process requires you to make changes to your map and alias files outside RoboHelp, and also to add a "redirector" topic to the master .chm file — so it is not straightforward.

Please see [Context IDs in Merged Help](http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/merge/ctx2).

So, you have to decide which one of the solutions is working for your needs.

Pete Lees mentioned some years ago "... that the HelpwareGroup.com site doesn't explain that the ALIAS section of the .hhp file must contain at least one bookmark-free reference to the redirect.htm file. If every redirect line in the section has a bookmark appended to it then the context help call will fail. So to fix the problem, add the following two lines to your .hhp file ...":

```
[ALIAS] 
Dummy_Unused=redirect.htm 

[MAP]
#define Dummy_Unused 0
```

Comment: since it has moved to xml, do i put this dummy entry in as follows in the Master's .ali file?  <alias name=Dummy_Unused link="redirect.htm"></alias>.  And i put the #define Dummy_Unused 0 in the BSSCDefault.h file?  This isn't clear since the format has changed or RoboHelp does it differently.  And do i need to include the .htm topic files from the slave projects somehow, like in the [FILES] section of the .hhp?  Thanks, I'm getting closer with your help

Comment: I'm not using RoboHelp and do my help authoring with [FAR HTML](http://www.help-info.de/en/FAR/far_html.htm). I give German support for FAR HTML (see: www.HelpwareGroup.com). I think you answered your question from the comment above by yourself - give it a try with XML in RoboHelp. I can't follow because I don't have a RoboHelp license. As mentioned above it is not straightforward. What's about additional help from RoboHelp user forum?

Comment: I didn't need the dummy entry (i don't really even know what a bookmark free reference is lol).  biggest problem was RoboHelp randomly was removing my redirect.xhtm entry from the .hhp and i didn't use the its- syntax in the redirect's link.